# Is there a way to optimize with a variable name loop?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, cout

I made a simple code that displays random characters in a 4x4 array. These unique characters are stored in arrays that are named die 1 to die 16. I show you a snippet of the code :

Here are my arrays with their names :

```
//Use of dice that contain unique characters
    char dice1[6]={'E', 'T', 'U', 'K', 'N', 'O'};
    char dice2[6]={'E', 'V', 'G', 'T', 'I', 'N'};
    char dice3[6]={'D', 'E', 'C', 'A', 'M', 'P'};
    char dice4[6]={'I', 'E', 'L', 'R', 'U', 'W'};
    char dice5[6]={'E', 'H', 'I', 'F', 'S', 'E'};
    char dice6[6]={'R', 'E', 'C', 'A', 'L', 'S'};
```

Here the output :

```
int main()
{
//init the random engine
    random_device rd;
    default_random_engine eng(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(MIN, MAX);
    cout << distr(eng) << endl;

            //Output of a random caracetere in the form of a table
            cout << dice1[distr(eng)] ;
            cout << dice2[distr(eng)] ;
            cout << dice3[distr(eng)] ;
            cout << dice4[distr(eng)] ;
            cout << endl;
            cout << dice5[distr(eng)] ;
            cout << dice6[distr(eng)] ;
            cout << dice8[distr(eng)] ;
            cout << endl;
```

Can we optimize this code with a loop? I thought about doing a for loop but I didn't find a convincing option to change the number at the end.

Comment: Try using a 2 dimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this. I didn't add the extra '\n' in there if needed use a indexed for loop (I used a range based for loop):

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

// note do not use : using namespace std;
    
int main()
{
    // initialization of a 2d array  char dices[6][6] would also work.
    std::array<std::array<char, 6>, 6> dices
    { {
        {'E', 'T', 'U', 'K', 'N', 'O'},
        {'E', 'V', 'G', 'T', 'I', 'N'},
        {'D', 'E', 'C', 'A', 'M', 'P'},
        {'I', 'E', 'L', 'R', 'U', 'W'},
        {'E', 'H', 'I', 'F', 'S', 'E'},
        {'R', 'E', 'C', 'A', 'L', 'S'},
    } };


    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine eng(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(0, dices[0].size()-1);

    for (const auto& dice : dices)
    {
        std::cout << dice[distr(eng)];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>` would also work in place of a 2-d array.

Comment: I also considered a constexpr array of string_views since strings are constant (and don't need dynamic allocation). I decided to keep close to existing char arrays.